# Build failed with error MSB4226: The imported project | REACT NATIVE WINDOWS

Tags: reactjs, windows, native

Visual studio 2017  and i am installed all required build tools  .but when i run react-native run-windows  . It show error like below code

```
C:\native\myapp>react-native run-windows
Restoring NuGet packages
Building C:/native/myapp/windows/com.tet.windows.sln
Found MSBuild v15.0 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin
Building Solution: C:/native/myapp/windows/com.tet.windows.sln
Build configuration: Debug
Build platform: x86
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
C:\native\myapp\windows\com.tet.windows\com.tet.windows.csproj(171,11): error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSha
rp.targets" was not found. Also, tried to find "Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v15.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets" i
n the fallback search path(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are
defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe.Config". Confir
m that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.Current.targets(1
08,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\
VC\VCTargets\Platforms\Win32\Platform.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is corr
ect, and that the file exists on disk. [C:\native\myapp\node_modules\react-native-windows\Folly\Folly.vcxproj]
Build failed with message Error: Command failed: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild.exe" "C:/native/myapp/windows/com.tet.windows.sln" /clp:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=quiet /nologo /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x86 /p:AppxBundle=Never /p:PlatformToolset=v141 /p:VisualStudioVersion=15.0. Check your build configuration.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got similar issue due to starting using VS 2019. All it says is that go to this file:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\bin\msbuild.exe.Config
```

open it and find what is in this node:

```
<projectImportSearchPaths>
      <searchPaths os="windows">
```

Change the value to navigate exactly where your MSBuild is right now. In my case, the change was:

```
<projectImportSearchPaths>
      <searchPaths os="windows">
        <property name="MSBuildExtensionsPath" value="$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise"/>
        <property name="MSBuildExtensionsPath32" value="$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise"/>
        <property name="MSBuildExtensionsPath64" value="$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise"/>
        <property name="VSToolsPath" value="$(MSBuildProgramFiles32)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)"/>
      </searchPaths>
    </projectImportSearchPaths>
```

value: **Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio**

Hope it helps.